# Why the interceptor brokes the wildcard in Struts 2?

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, interceptor, wildcard-mapping

**I have this action with wildcards:**

```
@Namespace("/posts")
public class SearchPostBeansAction extends ActionSupport{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SearchPostBeansAction.class); 
    
    @Override
    @Actions({
        @Action(value="/{search1}/{param1}/",results={ 
            @Result(name=ACTION_SUCCESS,location="classic.main.general", type="tiles")})    
    })
    public String execute() throws Exception {
           logger.info("Action: " + getInvocatedURL() );
           String forward = SUCCESS;
           logger.info("getSearch1( " + getSearch1() + " )");
           logger.info("getParam1( " + getParam1() + " )");
           return forward;
    }
}
```

**The result executed:**

```
 - INFO (com.silver.front.view.actions.SearchPostBeansAction) - Action:
   /posts/category/cars/
   
 - INFO (com.silver.front.view.actions.SearchPostBeansAction) -   
   getSearch1( category )

 - INFO (com.silver.front.view.actions.SearchPostBeansAction) -   
   getParam1( cars )
```

**If I intercept that action:**

```
@InterceptorRef("seoFilter")
@Namespace("/anuncios")
public class SearchPostBeansAction extends ActionSupport{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
}
```

**The result executed:**

```
 - INFO (com.silver.front.view.actions.SearchPostBeansAction) - Action:
   /posts/category/cars/
   
 - INFO (com.silver.front.view.actions.SearchPostBeansAction) -   
   getSearch1( null )

 - INFO (com.silver.front.view.actions.SearchPostBeansAction) -   
   getParam1( null)
```

**Why lost wildcard's parameters?**

**Here it´s interceptor:**

```
public class SEOFilter implements Interceptor{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SEOFilter.class); 
    
    ActionSupport actionSupport = null;
    
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        actionSupport = (ActionSupport) invocation.getAction();
        actionSupport.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think Why lost wildcards parameters?

Comment: when I try to get search1 or param1, I get a null value 

:(

Comment: try to set first then you'll be able to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I wanted!!! :)

Many Thanks Boris and Roman.

I just define a interceptor-stack.

```
<interceptors> 
    <interceptor name="seoFilter" class="com.silver.usaditos.admin.SEOFilter"></interceptor>
    <interceptor-stack name="defaultInterceptorStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="seoFilter"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you bypass all of the interceptors on the interceptor stack.

To use an `Interceptor` you need to call `invocation.invoke()` to tell struts to continue processing the request through the rest of the `Interceptor` stack.

You manually invoke the action thereby bypassing the interceptor stack.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    return invocation.invoke;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is you applied `@InterceptorRef("seoFilter")` to the action class and as you should know by convention it's applied to all actions in the class. Remove this and if you want to add a custom interceptor to the action use the `@Action` annotation.

```
@Action(value="/{search1}/{param1}/", results={ 
        @Result(name=ACTION_SUCCESS,location="classic.main.general", type="tiles")},
   interceptorRefs={@InterceptorRef("seoFilter"),@InterceptorRef("defaultStack")
})
```

Assumed that `seoFilter` is a valid interceptor that will not break the stack.

This is the code for a valid interceptor

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    // here you can place the code that used to intercept the action
    ...
    //finally
    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

As you didn't post the `struts.xml` and I *cannot see* how did you configure Struts to use with wildcard mappings I will provide you a reference for [advanced wildcards](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings#advanced-wildcards) from the documentation page to do it yourself.

Comment: Doesn´t work, i still getting same error. 
If I remove the interceptor, it´s run perfect. But I need that interceptor for other reason
:/

Comment: I said it should be a valid interceptor that will not break the stack. You should not execute the action from the interceptor because the action should execute at the bottom of the interceptor stack. All you need is just to continue invoking it after you fix the stack from this answer.

Comment: I removed actionSupport.execute() and put invocation.invoke(), but I still getting the same error :(

Comment: getters and setters provide to the params interceptor (which is alredy in the stack), I thought you configured to use wildcard parameters in action name.

Comment: You have given me a clue, I published the answer, Many thanks.